# jQuery Datepicker pre-select date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am working on a legacy project that use a datepicker as folows:

```
<script>
     DateInput('date', true, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
</script>
```

If I want to pre-select a date I simply have to provide a string as the 4th paramter:

```
DateInput('date', true, 'DD-MM-YYYY', '01-01-2015')
```

In my case I want to set the date when a click event:

```
$('.edit-news').click(function(){
    ....
    var date = $(this).data("date");
    ....
}
```

But how can I pass the value to the script tag. The datepicker plugin is quite old so perhaps my use case is beyond what is possible?

Link to docs:

http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm

Comment: Link to the datepicker docs?

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but I would look for another datepicker that works with jQuery. It's more comfortable and you already use jQuery anyway.

Comment: Investigating yet I do not see a method to change the default date after initialization. It can be done with jQuery with a secondary script. Will have to test. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
$(function() {
  function getDateText() {
    var dt = new Date();
    return [
      dt.getDate(),
      dt.getMonth(),
      dt.getFullYear()
    ];
  }

  $(".edit_news").click(function() {
    var nowDate = getDateText();
    $("#eg4_Month_ID").val(nowDate[1]).trigger("change");
    $("#eg4_Day_ID").val(nowDate[0]).trigger("change");
    $("#eg4_Year_ID").val(nowDate[2]).trigger("change");
  });
});
```

This is based on the example script at: http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm

```
DateInput('date', true, 'DD-MM-YYYY', '01-01-2015');
```

So the initial plug-in does not offer the option to modify the Default Date after initialization. If you want to set the date programmatically on a `click` event, something like the code above would work. You will need to fix it to match the ID or classes created in your page.

We set the value and then use `.trigger()` to trigger a change event on the element. This helps the primary script track the change properly.

I am unable to test it properly as you did not provide a complete example and the plug-in does not appear to have a CDN.

Personally, I would consider switching to a modern plugin, such as jQuery UI Datepicker: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/